# Как составить регулярное выражение, чтобы разбить строку по символу равенства

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день,читаю строки из файла.Не понимаю как правильно составить регулярное выражение,чтобы разбить строку на два слова.

```
line_sub = line.split("[\\s]{0,1}[\\=]{0,1}[\\:]{0,1}[\\s]{0,1}");
```

Сам текстовый файл:
key=value
key = value
key:value

Comment: Похоже что вы хотите прочитать так называемый property file. Если вы только учитесь, то полезно конечно, но вообще это изобретение велосипеда. С давних пор есть `java.util.Properties` с методом `load`, не говоря уже о более совершенных читалках параметров.

Comment: Да вы правы,я специально убрал вариант с пробелом,чтобы сразу на java.util.Properties не указывали,т.к. хотел разобраться  с регулярным выражением

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String[] split = line.split("(\\s?=\\s?|:)")
```

split[0] - key

split[1] - value

Comment: понял,спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Лучше `*` вместо `?`, кто знает сколько у него там пробелов)

Comment: Ну в вопросе не было много пробелов. Так же можно сюда еще запихнуть ; - вдруг у него будут key и value разделены точкой с запятой

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] result = line.split("[\\s?=\\s?]|[\\s?:\\s?]");
```

На случай, если и между двоеточиями будут пробелы.